# Best way to exclude unset fields from nested FastAPI model response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Assuming I have Pydantic-based FastAPI models similar to:

```py
class Filter(BaseModel, extra=Extra.forbid):
    expression: str | None
    kind: str | None
    ...

class Configuration(BaseModel):
    filter: Filter | None = {}
    ....
```

By default a model that is sent nothing for the filter will end up exporting like this:

```py
{
   "filter": {
       "expression": None,
       "kind": None,
       ...
   },
   ...
}
```

What I want instead is this:

```py
{
   "filter": {},
   ...
}
```

What is the best way to have the nested model always have the [exclude_unset](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/) behavior when exporting?

Sometimes in a complicated model I want some nested models to exclude unset fields but other ones to include them. I'm aware of [exclude_unset](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/) and [response_model_exclude_unset](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter), but both affect the entire model.

It feels like there should be a way to specify behavior for a nested model and have the be consistently respected, but I can't find how to do this. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: To me, the obvious question is, why don't you just handle this in the recipient?  You It's pretty easy to pre-process a struct like that and strip out `None` values.

Comment: @TimRoberts - It is pretty easy but it doesn't solve the response model issue. I can curate what persists, but then FastAPI populates the missing fields when responding to the client. 

It feels wrong to have to solve the problem on both ends when I'm defining everything else in the model.

Also if `response_model_exclude_unset` is set on one route with a given response model and not set another one with the same response model the output is inconsistent. What happens when the model is returned nested in another response? This feels like it should be a model concern, not a route concern?

Comment: Seems like you _did_ hack the problem away by setting an empty dictionary as the default value for `filter`. Aside from the inconsistent typing, what problems do you have with your approach? Or is there more context that you did not provide? Because right now, initializing `Configuration()` without setting `filter` gives your exact desired result (as mentioned in the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I have your example reproduced exactly as you need it. I am using the method [`.dict()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict)

```
>>> conf = Configuration()
>>> print(conf.dict())

>>> {'filter': {}}
```